# [SQL Server]Invalid column name: '2022-12-20 23:59:00'

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I migrated my MySQL database to SQL Server 2019.

Working fine with MySQL :

```
**$now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d 23:59:00');

->leftJoin('abonnements', function ($join) use ($now) {
                $join->on('abonnements.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
                ->whereRaw(DB::raw("NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM abonnements a1
                where a1.date_fin_tolerance >= \"{$now}\" and a1.date_debut <= \"{$now}\"
                and a1.client_id = clients.id
                AND a1.created_at > abonnements.created_at
              )"**
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name: '2022-12-20 23:59:00'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [customers] left join [subscriptions] on [subscriptions].[customer_id] = [customers].[id] and NOT EXISTS (\r\n SELECT 1 FROM subscriptions a1\r\n where a1.date_end_tolerance >= cast( "2022-12-20 23:59:00" as datetime) and a1.start_date <= cast("2022-12-20 23:59:00" as datetime)\r\n and a1.client_id = customers.id\r\n AND a1.created_at > subscriptions.created_at\r\n ) and [subscriptions].[end_tolerance_date] >= 2022-12-20 23:59:00 and [subscriptions].[start_date] < = 2022-12-20 23:59:00 left join [subscription_type] on [subscription_type].[subscription_type_id] = [subscription_type].[id] where [customers].[deleted_at] is null)"

Why it confuses the value with the column

Comment: Don't inject, and the issue goes away.

Comment: *"Why it confuses the value with the column"* Because you are saying it's a acolumn: `\"{$now}\"`. equates to `"2022-12-20 23:59:00"`, and your table doesn't have that column.

Comment: Why use a raw query when you can use `whereDoesntHave()`?  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: @Larnu Using parameters for a date range can have significant query plan implications.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft *injecting* parameters has a significant effect on security; it's a big no-no. There are plenty of ways of handling dates for *good* query plan generation, the fact that it using a parameter *might*cause a poor cache doesn't excuse the huge security risks injection presents.

Comment: Only injecting SQL based on user input or external data is a risk.  And even if were user input, here the type system of the client prevents SQL injection.  And I was just providing a caveat that replacing a date with a parameter might impact performance, and so require additional work to implement.  Not that it's a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are used for an identifier (e.g.: column or table name) within SQL Server.  Use single quotes to pass the datetime value as a string.

Comment: Thank you @CElliot Double quotes was the problem i changed it with Single quotes ... and that works for me